# Canvas не рисуется картинка на холсте

Tags: canvas, рисование

```
let cvs = document.querySelector('#cvs'),
      ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');
    let coin = {
      x: 100,
      y: 250,
      width: 40,
      heigth: 40,
      sx: 0,
      sy: 0,
      sw:  40,
      sh: 40,
      skin: 'img/coins.png'
    }

    let coin_skin = new Image();
    coin_skin.src = coin.skin;

    coin_skin.onload = function() {
      requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
    }

    let gameLoop = function() {
      drawImage();
      requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
    }

    function drawImage() {
      // if (coin.sy == 160) {
      //  coin.sy = 0;
      // }
      // coin.sy += coin.sh;
      ctx.drawImage(coin_skin, coin.sx, coin.sy, coin.sw, coin.sh, coin.x, coin.y, coin.width, coin.height);
    }
```

Не рисует на холсте монетку, но если написать так

```
ctx.drawImage(coin_skin,0,0,40,40,100,250,40,40);
```

То все рисуется, почему так?
Ссылка на картинку https://opengameart.org/content/spinning-coin

Answer (score 1):

Невнимательность. В ассоциативном массиве ошибка 'heigth'. Правильно будет 'height'